# Lua Ti-nspire platform.window:invalidate()

Tags: lua, ti-nspire

I've searched many places for what platform.window:Invalidate() exactly does to the drawing screen on the Ti-Nspire, but sadly no in-depth answers come up.

Some [sources](https://wiki.inspired-lua.org/platform.window:invalidate) say that by calling it 'invalidates' the window, [or](https://wiki.inspired-lua.org/timer.start) calls on.paint function. I don't exactly understand this, including why arguments can be included in the Invalidate(blah,blah2,blah3,blah4); does this mean that the on.paint function is called and can only repaint the portion defined, as if the other area not included in the argument is permanent?

Answer (score 1):

I just found [here](https://wiki.inspired-lua.org/on.paint) that the on.paint gets 'flagged to fire' upon calling platform.window:Invalidate().

> *The entire window can be forced to repaint with by calling the function with no arguments : platform.window:invalidate()*

If arguments are given, it will only be able to paint onto the area of x, y, width, height. The area outside of this outline is unaffected.